# How IIS recognize Chinese character in URL

Tags: python, django, iis

I was developing a django project and deploying it on IIS 7.5. I was using fileField in the model and try to upload files in the django admin. Some of the file names are in Chinese.

Before I deploy it on IIS 7.5, if I run the project with `python manage.py runserver` on the terminal, I can download the uploaded file with Chinese name. But after I deploy it on IIS, it seems like it can not recognized Chinese character. And it gives me an error like this:
[error pic link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUDVU.png)
Does any one knows what the problem is? I hope I explained the question with enough information.

Comment: it seems to be a bug in IIS 7, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25592621/7337499)

Comment: @EbrahimKarimi thank man, appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO yin, can you please post the text of the error in the question rather than providing links to pictures.